# Video Editor Text - Font Style Won't Change

Tags: video

I am using the Video Editor and have added a new Text object to the sequencer at the bottom. When I try to change the font style using the "Strip" menu to the right, selecting a new font style does not change the way the font is presented in the preview. Clicking the "F" button next to the Font style, I see a "0" next to the fonts I've tried. Can someone explain how I can get Blender to recognize different fonts besides the default? Thank you!

Comment: Jeff, are you able to place text in the VSE and with any font without using the Effects-->text strip?  If not leave a comment.

Comment: This may be related to this issue in the Blender bug tracker. I recommend you to monitor it: https://developer.blender.org/T80544

Answer (score 10):

I observed this behavior on Linux with Blender 2.83.5.

I found a workaround:

1. Create a font strip in VSE
2. Set the font you would like to use (the preview does not reflect this)
3. Delete the strip
4. Perform an undo. At least in my configuration, the text is rendered in the correct font.

Comment: Thanks.  Works for me on Windows 10 with Blender 2.90.1

Comment: Thanks! What I did is just added the font, then moved my timeline forward, and then pressed Control Z, and then the font appeared. This must be a bug in Blender.

Comment: Has someone reported this yet?

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi - Yes, as you can see in the comment I added to the original question (https://developer.blender.org/T80544)

Comment: Jesus Christ, Blender!